# Filtering data who time column is in milliseconds

Tags: sql, salesforce

I am trying to filter data of Salesforce API and the date column that I am trying to filter has time in milliseconds.

Given below is what I would normally use to filter date column but this does not work since the date column is in milliseconds.

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM table where LastModifiedDate > current_date - 1
```

But this does not work in this case and I believe it is because the time column is in milliseconds..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM table where SystemModStamp >= LAST_N_DAYS:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below format

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM account where SystemModStamp >= 2021-08-01T11:00:00Z and SystemModStamp <= 2021-09-01T11:00:55Z
```